# Error while running Docmd runsql using variable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I know i am asking an easy question, 
I Wasn't able to find the cause for the Problem.
When i run the followng code it gives me error in Docmd RunSqL Command showing invalid arguement. It seems that it could be due to variable ListTablename.

Here is my Code

```
 Function RefreshedLinks()
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim stringsql As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim Foldername As String
    Dim strTableNameCheck
    Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
    Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table Valued Parameter")
    ListTablename = "SELECT [LE Based Table].[Table Name], [LE Based Table].LE FROM [LE Based Table] WHERE ((([LE Based Table].LE)=[Forms]![Combo Box]![LE Select]));"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    DoCmd.RunSQL ListTablename

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End Function
```

The where condition of query is a string function based on selection done by user on the form combo box like XLL,XLI

Is there something wrong with my query?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case why you don't just insert values into SQL:

```
 ListTablename = "SELECT [LE Based Table].[Table Name], [LE Based Table].LE FROM [LE Based Table]
 WHERE ((([LE Based Table].LE)=" & [Forms]![Combo Box]![LE Select] & "));"
```

Sorry, but `RunSQL` could be used for an action query or a data-definition query. So create query, save it to db and then use `DoCmd.OpenQuery`

Comment: Insert into sql? Can you elaborate that

Comment: Are you saying why dont run the query in SQL?

Comment: in the upper code SQL string `ListTablename` will contain the value of `[Forms]![Combo Box]![LE Select]` itself, instead of reference to control.

Comment: So what i am getting , I need to use Docmd.openquery rather than Docmd runsql?

Comment: @Mohit if you want to show results to the user - it is the easiest way. And query in your Q is totally ready for this way.

Comment: What i want to acheive is if user select an items in Listbox. i want to create a link with the name selected in the listbox from a selected path